# Dynamically changing a jQuery Validate rule when a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation to validate a form, and what I would like to do is this... I want it set so if a checkbox is checked than a editbox is validated differently, for example.

This is how it should be validate if the checkbox is not checked:

```
weight: { required: true, max: 50 }
```

This is how it should be validated if it is checked.

```
weight: { required: true, max: 100 }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd use the [Validate plugin's built-in `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) to dynamically change the rule whenever the checkbox is clicked.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize the plugin
    $('#myform').validate({ 
        // other options,
        rules: {
            // other rules,
            weight: {
                required: true,
                max: 50 // initial value on load
            }
        }
    });

    // change the rule on checkbox and update displayed message dynamically
    $('#check').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#weight').rules('add', {
                max: 100
            });
        } else {
            $('#weight').rules('add', {
                max: 50
            });
        };
        $('#weight.error').each(function () {
            $(this).valid();
        });
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3hGxS/**

Answer (score 3):

Make a rule using the the [max](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/max#value) method and a function as a parameter.  This will get evaluated when the field is validated, ie when element() is called on the field.

rules definition looks like this

```
rules: {
    field1:
    {
        required: true,
        max: function () { return $("#mycheckbox:checked").length ? 100 : 50; }
    }
}
```

Also, revalidate the target field when rule changes or you may be left with an error message that no longer applies

```
$('#mycheckbox').on('change', function () {
    $('#field1.error').each(function () {
        $(this).valid();
    });
});
```

note that this only revalidates the field if it is already validated, checking for the presence of the default errorClass 'error'.

with html like this

```
<input name="mycheckbox" id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" />
<input name="field1" id="field1">
<input type="submit" />
```

Full JavaScript code is like this, [find the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jVznt/1/)

```
$(function () {

   $("form").validate({
        rules: {
          field1:
          {
            required: true,
            max: function () {
                    return $("#mycheckbox:checked").length ? 100 : 50;
                }
            }
         },
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert('form ok');
        }
    });

    $('#mycheckbox').on('change', function () {
        $('#field1.error').each(function () {
            $(this).valid();
        });
    });

});
```